# Visual Studio Setup Project Localization of System Controls

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation, visual-studio-setup-proje

I'm trying to create a Setup using Visual Studio Setup Project. A mistake, but there's legacy work to consider here.

Generally speaking, these projects do not support localization. However, almost all the Setups I've seen have some basic localization i.e., controls such as the Next button show the localized text. My setup project shows the Next button as Next regardless of the System UI language.

My question is - Is there a way to make Setup Project respect the System's UI language for these standard system controls? How?

BTW, my Visual Studio version is 2010.

Thanks,
Asaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MSI itself has no support for this.  The text for the controls is hard-baked into the "Control" table of the MSI file.

You *can* create a localized installer with a Setup project.  In the Properties window, change the Localization property.  This property is used to choose the corresponding .wid file from the common7\tools\deployment\vsddialogs\xxxx subdirectory of the VS install directory.  These are pre-cooked msi files with localized dialogs.

Getting the right language version of the resulting setup msi or exe to your user is your burden.  Microsoft does so by letting the user override the language on the download page.  English users are directed to a `http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en` page for example.